# Decoding error message from tracker

Tags: python, encoding, bittorrent

I am trying to decode an error message from a UDP tracker. 
below is my code.

```
import struct, socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
info_hash  = "%1D%D4%D1%EDQn%DB%5CL%83%90%1B%2B%F8%83%A2%19%C0%7C%98"
peer_id = "-UT1234-m%09%B2%D5%99%FA%1Fj%88%AC%0D%A7"
action =1 # announce
downloaded = 0
left = 0
uploaded = 0
event =0
ip = 0
key = 0
num_want = -1
port = 9999
announce_pack = struct.pack(">QLL20s20sQQQLLLLi",connection_id,action,transaction_id,info_hash,peer_id,down  loaded,left,uploaded,event,ip,key,num_want,port)
client_socket.sendto(announce_pack, ("tracker.ccc.de", 80))
res = client_socket.recv(1024)
try:
   action = struct.unpack(">HLLLLQQQ20s20sLLH", res[:98])
except Exception as e:
   error_action, error_tid, error_message = struct.unpack(">ii8s", res)
   raise TrackerRequestException(error_message.decode('utf-16'), "")
```

i am able to unpack the message but for some reason i am getting error message a

```
\uc061\u51be\u5841\ud3bf
```

how do I decode this into proper text?

I got the protocol description from this link http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html

Comment: It doesn't say anywhere in that the error message is UTF-16 encoded. Why are you decoding it as such?

Comment: Not that I can make any sense of the message encoding it back to UTF-16 data, little or big endian..

Comment: Also, you may not have read all the data yet; `socket.recv(1024)` can return fewer bytes if not all data has arrived yet. Don't just decode the data you did receive as an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be an exception for any number of reasons; you could have read too little data for example (`socket.recv(1024)` can return fewer bytes if that's all that's available at that time).

You need to follow the BEP more closely. You need to check that you have received *at least 8 bytes* first, and then check for the TID, and the action code. *Only if your action code is set to 3* is the response an error message.

The message is not encoded in UTF-16. It should just be ASCII data.